# String Array Assignment in Java

Tags: java, arrays, variable-assignment

Code:

```
String Foo[];
Foo={"foo","Foo"};
```

Error at Line 2: Illegal Start of expression
The code works if I say:

```
String Foo[]={"foo","Foo"};
```

Why does this happen, and how should I do the required without generating an error? This also happens with other data types.

Would appreciate if you could explain in **layman terms**.

Comment: The compiler want's you to specifiy that `{"foo", ...}` is meant to be an array, so use `new String[]{"foo", ...}`. Besides that, do yourself a favor and let variable names start with a lower case character, i.e. `String foo` instead of `String Foo` (and I personally like to have the array declaration at the type, i.e. `String[] foo`).

Comment: `Initialization`  and `Assignment` these are two words that makes the difference. I believe. :)

Comment: FYI: alternatively, for unmodifiable list rather than simple array, `List<String> list = List.of( "foo" , "bar" ) ;` as a single line or two lines.

Comment: normally you have to use `new String[] { ...}` (this was an always must in earlier versions of Java), but, as a syntactic sugar, the compiler accepts just `{ ... }` in a field declaration or variable declaration. Why? it is specified that way in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) (probably it would be to *messy* to accept it everywhere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{"foo","Foo"}` is an *array initializer*  and it isn't a complete [*array creation expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10):

> An array initializer may be specified **in a declaration** (§8.3, §9.3, §14.4), or **as part of an array creation expression** (§15.10), to create an array and provide some initial values.
>
> <sup>[Java Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)</sup>

Use `new String[] {"foo","Foo"}` instead.

Comment: What does '§' mean?

Comment: @StephenAllen a link to a specification section

Comment: @StephenAllen actually it is just an abbreviation for Section Sign - https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/176968 or https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/§ (happens to be a link to the given section in the Java Language Specification)

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the string array:

```
String foo[] = new String[]{"foo, "Foo"}; Or 
String foo[] = {"foo, "Foo"};
```

Modern IDEs give error for not initializing the array objects. You can refer more details here: 
http://grails.asia/java-string-array-declaration